# Can volley show the full HTTP request / response?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-volley

Can [Volley](https://google.github.io/volley/) show the full HTTP request / response?

I already use `VolleyLog.DEBUG = true` and that does show several logging messages, but not the HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

volley cannot show the HTTP request/ response
you can also look at this https://google.github.io/volley/simple.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).